# NextJS load react component at runtime

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, next.js, runtime

I want to create a react based theme engine for **NextJS**, in summary, the user can upload a set of `.js` files that contains React components, and I want to inject them inside my app on some specific parts.

The question is: It is possible to compile react component and inject them in my app after build and at runtime?

I also open to suggestions, still looking for an alternative of this.

Comment: Yes. Next.js supports ES2020 dynamic `import()` for JavaScript. With it you can import JavaScript modules dynamically and work with them. They also work with SSR.

Comment: @PsyGik seem like the files have to be there on build time, and I'm looking for something that let the user upload react files on runtime (after the build when the app is deployed)

Comment: If your React component is a CommonJS module and is already transpiled for browser support, I'd recommend checking out [remote-component](https://github.com/Paciolan/remote-component). Unfortunately, I do not know if Nextjs natively supports remote component render on runtime.